# actionbar disappears when extending listActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm using `API 23` and as I extended `ListActivity`,then my `ActionBar` items including menu items and title disappeared.
I couldn't find any solution for this. I'll appreciate if anyone could help me with this issue.

here's manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Please post some code or error logs and describe your situation. This will help the community to understand the question better and provide a good answer.

Comment: Please post your manifest

Comment: `actionbar disapears when extending listActivity` Yes, **obviously**! You must extend **AppCompatActivity**

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem with theme, what you have choose in your application.

**Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
```

Here i'm using `NoActionBar` theme, so please check your application theme in `manifest file`--> `<application>`-->`android:theme="@style/?"`

Suggestions: `Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` theme.